# Using lsyncd for backing up a server

Tags: lsyncd

Currently I am using rsync to make a daily backup of my rails server.
It is not a great solution because I have a million of files and it takes a very long time to scan them all and find any new file.
I am thinking of using lsyncd for backing up.

My question is, is it a good idea? Would it be able to handle a million files in thousands of directories, and a new file created every, say, 30 seconds?
Files are not supposed to change after they have been created.

I think it should work, but I am not sure if lsyncd has to register each file it wants to watch or if it can just watch for one root directory and get notified for each change, then send them to the backup server.